# Python decorator for data analytics class

Tags: python, python-decorators

I need to create a decorator function that multiplies the input parameter of a function by ten before the function is called. Next, create a function called normal_function that takes an input value and displays the result. Test your decorator to ensure the displayed value is ten times larger than what was passed into normal_function.

```
def mult_decorator_function(a_normal_function):
  x = a_normal_function() * 10
  return x

@mult_decorator_function
def normal_function(x):
  print(x)

normal_function(10)
```

Comment: A decorator should always return a callable, like a function. Also, your approach does not multiply the input argument but the returned result.

Comment: Is normal_function the input argument?  I think I am confused on what that actually is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to have nested function for decorators, also need to have `return` instead of `print`:

```
def mult_decorator_function(a_normal_function):
    def wrapper(x):
        x = a_normal_function(x) * 10
        return x
    return wrapper

@mult_decorator_function
def normal_function(x):
  return x

print(normal_function(10))
```

Output:

```
100
```

Comment: Oh, so that's why the wrapper is needed.  Great, thank you for the help!